# setState hook not updating

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have a header that I want to hide on scroll down and show on scroll up.
To do that, I saved the scrolling position as `prevScrollPos` in the state to compare it to the current scrolling position *`onscroll`*, and then update `prevScrollPos` to the current:

```
 const [visible, setVisible] = React.useState(true);
 const [prevScrollPos, setPrevScrollPos] = React.useState(window.pageYOffset);

  const handleScroll = () => {
    const scrollPos = window.pageYOffset;
    const visible = scrollPos < prevScrollPos;

    setVisible(visible);
    setPrevScrollPos(scrollPos);
  }
```

The problem is that, for some reason `PrevScrollPos` doesn't get updated.
Pen: https://codepen.io/moaaz_bs/pen/jgGRoj?editors=0110

Comment: I tested it on your `pen`. It works correctly

Comment: @TienDuong Check the console

Comment: When you add the scroll handler then handle scroll function is bind to the first `prevScrollPos` value. See this answer to solve your problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55265255/react-usestate-hook-event-handler-using-initial-state

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to modify your useEffect function:

```
  React.useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener('scroll', handleScroll);
    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener('scroll', handleScroll);
    };
  });
```

Basically you don't have access to `prevScrollPos` in your handler, therefore prevScrollPos inside the listener will always return 0. To solve this, the dependency array should not be present.

-> + Do not forget to remove the event listener after adding it. :-)

Comment: Thank you so much! It worked. 
Do I need to remove the event listener event if the component will never unmount?

Comment: Now, you need to remove it since the event listener gets added with each render. And we need to have it because we want to be aware of the current prevScrollPos - otherwise we won't (as you saw). But in general, I would always make sure to remove the event listeners anyway, yes.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. I get it now

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this:

```
 const [visible, setVisible] = React.useState(true);
 const [prevScrollPos, setPrevScrollPos] = React.useState(window.pageYOffset);

  const handleScroll = () => {
    const scrollPos = window.pageYOffset;
    const visible_new = scrollPos < prevScrollPos;

    setVisible(visible_new);
    setPrevScrollPos(scrollPos);
  }
```

Comment: I thought that the problem concerned the visible variable which represents the state and which it seems to me is not correctly modified here: const visible = scrollPos <prevScrollPos; it's better to use another variable at this level