# Not able to access react state from socket event handler function

Tags: reactjs, socket.io

I have a react app where I am using socket.io for realtime messaging. I am trying to use common socket object across all react functional components, but in event handler function I am not able to access state objects.

Config:

```
var socket = io(socketEndPoint)
socket.emit('register', cookies)
export { socket }
```

ChatComponent:

```
import {socket} from './Config'
export default function ChatComponent(props) {
  const [chats, setChat] = React.useState([{chat_id: 1234}])
  socket.on('message', (data) => {
    console.log(data)
    console.log(chats)
  })
}
```

console.log(chats) always prints an empty array.

I tried using Context Api but still not help. Is there any way to access react state. Thanks in advance.

Comment: add here your code

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The answer seems elaborated in this article:
https://medium.com/geographit/accessing-react-state-in-event-listeners-with-usestate-and-useref-hooks-8cceee73c559

Which references also this post:

[React useState hook event handler using initial state](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55265255/react-usestate-hook-event-handler-using-initial-state)

## Update 2021 react functional component

```
const [chats, setChats] = useState([])

...

socket.on('message', function (messageData) {
    
    setChats((prev) => {
        return [chat, ...prev]
    }
});
```