# React : printing all past state when updating state

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm curioused about the work of this code.
It's a simple code, I intended to raise counter for 1 and print on console.

but when I click the button the counter increases, also printing from 0 ~ to all the number that I increased.

[run screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eKaL5.png)

Could you explain why this happens?

```js
import { useState } from "react";

function App() {
  const [counter, setCounter] = useState(0);

  const onClick = () => {
    window.addEventListener("click", () => {
      console.log(counter);
    });
    setCounter((counter) => counter + 1);
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <button onClick={() => onClick()}>Add & Print!</button>
      <div>{counter}</div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: If my answer was helpful then select my answer please!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You added `onClick` event to `button` tag and when the function is executed, `onClick` event to `window` is added. So whenever clicking `button` tag, `addEventListener` that order to add shows `console.log` is made. On the code, showing `console.log` doesn't need `addEventListener` because `button` tag already has `onClick` event.

In `<button onClick={() => onClick()}>Add & Print!</button>` tag, `onClick` event is executed whenever the tag is clicked,

Below,

```
    window.addEventListener("click", () => {
      console.log(counter);
    });
```

`addEventListener` adds event.

So whenever clicking `button` tag, `addEventListener` is executed(that adds events).

```
import { useState } from "react";

function App() {
  const [counter, setCounter] = useState(0);

  const onClick = () => {
// doesn't need window.addEventListener
//    window.addEventListener("click", () => {
      console.log(counter);
//    });
    setCounter((counter) => counter + 1);
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <button onClick={() => onClick()}>Add & Print!</button>
      <div>{counter}</div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Absolutely Clear Answer!!
Thanks to kind, thoughtful answer! :>

Comment: @Chanmin Happy to be helpful :) Hope your React journey will be wonderful :)

Answer (score 0):

On every click you are adding an event listener. So on first click there is one event listener, on second 2, on third three and so on. (on nth click, n event listeners are there on window object).

There is also the situation of the event listener using **[stale state](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55265255/react-usestate-hook-event-handler-using-initial-state)**. The window event listener has **[closed over](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures)**(closures) the old value of state and is logging it. So the first event listener is always using count = 0. The third event listener is using count = 2. So, on.