# Can I update state inside nested function in react functional component?

Tags: reactjs, react-state

```js
function App(){

  const [listState, setListState] = useState([]);

  let connectWebsocket = () => {
    let ws = new WebSocket(`ws://${window.location.host}/ws`);
    ws.onmessage = (event) => {
      let data = JSON.parse(event.data);
      setListState([...listState, data]);
    };
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(listState); // Problem: This always logs empty array.
  }, [listState]);

  useEffect(() => {
    connectWebsocket();
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>

    </div>
  );
}
```

When I update state in nested functions, the state is updated to an initial value.
How to fix this problem?

Comment: help us help you, attach the necessary code to debug

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Nobody can tell you what's wrong with code we can't see.  Please provide a [mcve] demonstrating the problem.  To learn more about this community and how we can help you, please start with the [tour] and read [ask] and its linked resources.

Comment: @ahliru: Can you confirm that this is a *React* issue and not a problem with the websocket or the data it returns?  If I replace the websocket code with a hard-coded `Promise` to simulate the same "nested function" structure then this works as expected.  Could you create a runnable example to demonstrate the specific React problem you're describing?

Comment: `setListState([...listState, data]);` change to `setListState(currentListState => [...currentListState, data]);` ->  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55265255/react-usestate-hook-event-handler-using-initial-state

Comment: @David I think this is a not problem with the websocket. What do you mean "hard-coded Promise"?