# Firebase and React Native subcribe to changes (onSnapshot) not working properly

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

I am having trouble subscribing to changes in Firebase's Firestore. I am developing my first React Native project with Firebase, therefore i am not really familiar with Firebase.

The Firebase connection is working: I can add and read data from the Firstore.

So far I have tried to replicate this issue: [React useState and Firebase onSnapshot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70214878/react-usestate-and-firebase-onsnapshot) which did not work for me.

```
useEffect(() => {
    const q = query(collection(db, "rooms"), where("active", "==", "true"));
    const unsubscribe = onSnapshot(q, (querySnapshot) => {
      setUser(querySnapshot);
    });
    console.log("User: " + user);
    return () => {
      unsubscribe();
    };
  }, []);
```

When I run it I get the following output `User: undefined`

I have also tried this approach:

```
const q = query(collection(db, "rooms"), where("active", "==", "true"));
const unsubscribe = onSnapshot(q, (querySnapshot) => {
  querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
    console.log(doc);
  });
});
unsubscribe();
```

That's not working either.

Here you can see my Firestore:
[Firestore](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F8qOH.png)

Is there anything I am missing? Your help is really appreciated!

Comment: Have you checked [How to get data from firestore DB in outside of onSnapshot](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52488087/13130697) ? The `console.log()` current runs even before `onSnapshot` has fetched data. Also if you have store 'true' as a boolean value in Firestore then use `where("active", "==", true)` instead of `where("active", "==", "true")` otherwise the query is looking for active field where it's string.

Comment: If I understand it correctly, I need the function "onSnapshot" to subscribe changes. I don't want to read the data only once, but I want to get continuous changes in the firestore.

Answer (score 0):

`onSnapshot` , `setUser` and other calls that manipulate state, are asynchronous, so you have to make sure you log them **after** the asynchronous operation has completed.

That's why your call to `setUser(querySnapshot);` is *inside* the callback, as that ensures it happens after the `querySnapshot` is available from the database.

If you want to see the value that you get from the database, log it inside the callback like this:

```
const unsubscribe = onSnapshot(q, (querySnapshot) => {
  console.log("Snapshot: " + querySnapshot.size);
  setUser(querySnapshot);
});
```

Similarly, if you want to show the updated state, you can pass a callback to `setUser`, which then is called once the state is updated:

```
const unsubscribe = onSnapshot(q, (querySnapshot) => {
  console.log("Snapshot: " + querySnapshot.size);
  setUser(querySnapshot, () => {
    console.log("User: " + user.size);
  });
});
```

Comment: I'm afraid I'm still having some problems understanding how the onSnapchat function is working. Do I need to call unsubscribe() afterwards, or how does this function get called?

Comment: "still having some problems" is hard to help with. Did you apply the changes I showed and explained in my answer? What output do you see on the console with those changes?

Comment: Unfortunately, I did not get any logs in the console. Maybe I am not calling the function the right way... I have tried it with a simple call to unsubscribe() but that did not lead to any improvements.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have created an index on the fields that you are using in where and order by clause. You can create it by going to firebase console -> Firestore Database -> indexes.

[image: how to add index index in firestore]