# How do I store an HTML elements offsetTop on initial React.js render to be used with a scroll event listener?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I'm making a "sticky" header when `scrollY` meets `offsetTop`, but I don't want to hard code the offset. I've been attempting to store the initial `offsetTop` which can then be checked inside the `isSticky()` method attached to the `scroll` listener.

So far I've been unable to make the value stick (no pun intended) and it appears to be `null` inside the method being run.

```
const ProfileHeader: React.FC<ProfileHeaderData> = ({ profile }) => {
    const bannerUrl = getBannerImageUrl(profile.id, null, profile.bannerImageVersion);
    const logoUrl = getLogoImageUrl(profile.id, null, profile.logoImageVersion);
    const headerRef = useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null);

    const [sticky, setSticky] = useState("");
    const [headerOffSet, setHeaderOffSet] = useState<number>(null);

    console.log(`Outside: ${headerOffSet}`);

    // on render, set listener
    useEffect(() => {
        console.log(`Render: ${headerRef.current.offsetTop}`);
        setHeaderOffSet(headerRef.current.offsetTop);

        window.addEventListener("scroll", isSticky);
        return () => {
            window.removeEventListener("scroll", isSticky);
        };
    }, []);

    const isSticky = () => {
        /* Method that will fix header after a specific scrollable */
        const scrollTop = window.scrollY;
        let originalOffset = headerOffSet ?? headerRef.current.offsetTop;
        if (headerOffSet === null) {
            console.log(`Setting header off set`);
            setHeaderOffSet(originalOffset);
        }
        console.log(`top: ${scrollTop} | offset: ${originalOffset} | state: ${headerOffSet}`);
        const stickyClass = scrollTop >= originalOffset ? styles.sticky : "";
        setSticky(stickyClass);
    };

    return (
        <div className={styles.container}>
            <div className={styles.bannerContainer}>
                {profile.bannerImageVersion && (
                    <Image
                        src={bannerUrl}
                        layout='fill'
                        className={styles.banner}
                    />
                )}
            </div>
            <div ref={headerRef} className={`${styles.header} ${sticky}`}>
                <div className={styles.logoContainer}>
                    {profile.logoImageVersion && (
                        <Image
                            src={logoUrl}
                            layout='fill'
                            className={styles.logo}
                        />
                    )}
                </div>
                <FlagCircleIcon {...profile.country} size={32} />
                <h1 className={styles.displayName}>{profile.displayName}</h1>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

On the initial page load, I get the following console output:

[image]

As I start to scroll, the output is as follows:

[image]

Seems like the state is never set?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a blog post explaining that you need to use a reference (`useRef`) and access the value via that inside the listener.

https://medium.com/geographit/accessing-react-state-in-event-listeners-with-usestate-and-useref-hooks-8cceee73c559

This references another SO post:

[React useState hook event handler using initial state](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55265255/react-usestate-hook-event-handler-using-initial-state)

**EDIT**

Providing working example based on original question code and solution provided by the blog post. The change the key change is to have a references to the `useState` variables and read from those inside the event listener.

```
import { useEffect, useRef, useState } from 'react';

import styles from './testComponent.module.scss';

export const TestComponent: React.FC = ({ children }) => {
    const headerRef = useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null);

    const [sticky, _setSticky] = useState(false);
    const stickyRef = useRef(sticky);
    const setSticky = (data: boolean) => {
        stickyRef.current = data;
        _setSticky(data);
    }

    const [headerOffSet, _setHeaderOffSet] = useState<number>(null);
    const headerOffSetRef = useRef(headerOffSet);
    const setHeaderOffSet = (data: number) => {
        headerOffSetRef.current = data;
        _setHeaderOffSet(data);
    }

    const isSticky = () => {
        const scrollTop = window.scrollY;
        const isSticky = scrollTop >= headerOffSetRef.current;

        setSticky(isSticky);
    };

    // on render, set listener
    useEffect(() => {
        setHeaderOffSet(headerRef.current.offsetTop);

        window.addEventListener("scroll", isSticky);
        return () => {
            window.removeEventListener("scroll", isSticky);
        };
    }, []);

    return (
        <div className={styles.container}>
            <div ref={headerRef} className={`${styles.header} ${sticky ? styles.isSticky : null}`}>
                {children}
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
```