# ReactJS executes both if and else statement

Tags: reactjs, leaflet, react-leaflet

I'm trying to build this little project with React Leaflet in which by searching through the leaflet-geosearch search bar a certain city, after clicking on it, a form should pop up asking for some reviews about the place. I want to add a prevent duplicate clause in the handler of the geosearch bar using the array of already rated places that I'm passing to the SearchBar component as a prop. When i try to verify if the cities arr already has an object with the same id, it just doesn't early return, it ignores the early return completely.

CODE///

```
export default function SearchBar({
  onSubmitCityMapSearch,
  setCurrLocation,
  onSetFocus,
  cities,
}) {
  function handler(event) {
    const {
      location: {
        label,
        y,
        x,
        raw: { place_id },
      },
    } = event;

    
    const exists = cities.every((city) => city.location.id !== place_id);
    if (!exists) {
      console.log("It exists"); /*used to be an early return which wouldn't get executed. In this case the cl does get executed, same as the else block*/
    } else {
      onSubmitCityMapSearch();
      setCurrLocation({ label, location: [y, x], id: place_id });
      onSetFocus(place_id);
    }
  }

  const provider = new OpenStreetMapProvider();

  const searchControl = new GeoSearchControl({
    provider: provider,
    style: "bar",
    showMarker: false,
  });

  const map = useMap();
  useEffect(() => {
    map.addControl(searchControl);
    return () => map.removeControl(searchControl);
  }, []);

  map.on("geosearch/showlocation", handler);
  return null;
}
```

I tried with an if/else statement and in that case it executes both if and else statements. I tried doing some research on it, but to no avail. Anyone has any deeper understanding why this could be happening? The code is a little bit messy, I'm really new to React.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're adding your handler **every time** your component is rendered, so you end up with multiple versions of your handler function attached, which close over *different copies* of `cities`. So when the event occurs, your handler is called multiple times, and reports the results that are valid for its copy of `cities`. If you're seeing both the `if` branch taken and the `else` branch taken, it's because one of the handlers is taking the `if` branch and *another* handler is taking the `else` branch.

You have at least two options:

1. Hook up your handler in a `useEffect` callback with `cities` as a dependency, and unhook it in the effect's cleanup (you should be doing that in any case), like this:

   ```
   useEffect(() => {
       function handler(event) {
           const {
               location: {
                   label,
                   y,
                   x,
                   raw: { place_id },
               },
           } = event;

           const exists = cities.every(
               (city) => city.location.id !== place_id
           );
           if (!exists) {
               console.log(
                   "It exists"
               ); /*used to be an early return which wouldn't get executed. In this case the cl does get executed, same as the else block*/
           } else {
               onSubmitCityMapSearch();
               setCurrLocation({ label, location: [y, x], id: place_id });
               onSetFocus(place_id);
           }
       }
       map.on("geosearch/showlocation", handler);
       return () => {
           // This function is called when cleaning up
           map.off("geosearch/showlocation", handler);
           //  ^^^−−−− or whatever the "unregister" function is
       }
   }, [cities]);
   ```

   Note that this means your handler will be removed and the the new one attached every time `cities` changes. In most cases, that's harmless.
2. If for some reason you want to only attach the handler once, you need a different way of accessing `cities` so that you're always accessing an up-to-date version of it. A common way to do that is to use a ref. You'd do that by declaring the ref and assigning `cities` to it in top-level code inside your component function, then hook up your event handler inside your `useEffect(___, [])` callback, which only runs on mount, and have the code use `citiesRef.current` instead of `cities`:

   ```
   const citiesRef = useRef(null);
   citiesRef.current = cities;

   useEffect(() => {
       function handler(event) {
           const {
               location: {
                   label,
                   y,
                   x,
                   raw: { place_id },
               },
           } = event;

           const cities = citiesRef.current; // <================================
           const exists = cities.every(
               (city) => city.location.id !== place_id
           );
           if (!exists) {
               console.log(
                   "It exists"
               ); /*used to be an early return which wouldn't get executed. In this case the cl does get executed, same as the else block*/
           } else {
               onSubmitCityMapSearch();
               setCurrLocation({ label, location: [y, x], id: place_id });
               onSetFocus(place_id);
           }
       }

       map.addControl(searchControl);
       map.on("geosearch/showlocation", handler);
       return () => {
           map.removeControl(searchControl);
           map.off("geosearch/showlocation", handler);
           //  ^^^−−−− or, again, whatever the "unregister" function is
       }
   }, []);
   ```

   That works because `citiesRef` is a *stable* reference to an object (it will always point to the same object, consistent across calls to your component function), and we update `citiesRef.current` on every call, so the code in the handler is always using an up-to-date version of the cities.

See also the answers to these questions (they talk about state members rather than props, but the underlying issue the same same — referencing stale copies of them:

- [*React useState hook event handler using initial state*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55265255/react-usestate-hook-event-handler-using-initial-state)
- [*Wrong React hooks behaviour with event listener*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53845595/wrong-react-hooks-behaviour-with-event-listener)